# laravel AppServiceProvider extending rules for array validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to check particular id list using whereIn.

Ex:-

```
"id" : [1,2,3]
```

The rule will be like,

```
return [
    'id' : 'custom_validation:users,id', 
];
```

I'm using the request file for this validation.
  I will using AppServiceProvider for custom validation and there will be like,

```
whereIn('id', $parameter[1]);
```

i.e.,

```
Validator::extend('custom_validation', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
 $count = DB::table($parameters[0])->whereIn($parameters[1], Input::get($parameters[1]))
            ->get();
        if ($count)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
});
```

But. I'm getting an error of "Array to string conversion" ErrorException in Grammar.php line 210:

I'm new to laravel and i searched. But i can't find related answer.

Comment: How are you making this request? i.e. are you using JSON or literally just passing the string `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin `dd($parameters[1])` will show `'id'`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean what does `dd(Input::get($parameters[1]))` show?

Comment: It is throwing error also for Input::get()

Comment: Please can you edit your answer so show the contents `dd($value)`?